# Any technique in Umbraco to identify which XSLT is being sluggish when transformed?

Tags: xslt, azure, umbraco

I'm getting some very slow performance from an Umbraco site hosted on my Azure account.  The account runs two sites, both set to an `extrasmall` size and running with two instances for failover.

**Edited for clarity --**

There are two sites available in each instance. Of those two sites, one works fine, the other is very slow (despite being served from the same instance, the same IIS etc.).

**--**

I started by checking the Azure instances, they seem ok and aren't struggling particularly (usual tools: task manager, resource monitor, perfmon etc).  Both sites run from SQL Azure and there seems to be little to no lag there.

Next I ran my sluggish site with the `?umbdebugshowtrace=true` querystring, and most of the delay is happening at this point in the page lifecycle:

```
Category Message FromFirst(ms) FromLast(ms)

umbracoMacro Before performing transformation 0.858817787142857 0.000024

Resolve Urls 0 11.9020404352381 11.043223

umbracoMacro After performing transformation 11.9022704233333 0.000230
```

Running the XSLT transformation is taking about 11 seconds.

So I've done some investigative hacking and basically stripped out every XSLT control on the page, one at a time, none of them (individually) seem to be causing the hang.

**Does anyone have any recommendations for how I can dig further into this and perhaps get a little more information on exactly where the delay is?**

It's great that I have enough data to narrow it down to an XSLT transformation issue, but more information would be awesome :)

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Karl.

Comment: You forgot to provide the XSLT transformation and the source XML document that it is applied on. It is quite probable that your XSLT code implements some inefficient algorithm such as an O(N^2) one. If you aren't providing this necessary information, then what is it you are asking about? It's raining in Seattle...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev My apologies for being unclear, I would like to know if there was a way in Umbraco to find out which XSLT was causing the render delay, rather than hacking controls out one after another to locate it: "Does anyone have any recommendations for how I can dig further into this and perhaps get a little more information on exactly where the delay is?"  Naturally if I knew which of my XSLT controls the delay was in I would be busy fixing it :)

Comment: Karl, then the title of the question is somewhat misleading: "What can cause Umbraco to be sluggish when transforming XSLT?" The answer is obvious: The cause is the inefficient code of the XSLT transformation. In other words, if Umbraco was performing OK with other apps, the cause for this different behavior is in the difference between the current app and the apps that are running OK. So, think what is different, what is new -- this is what causes the slow behavior. And the one by one turning offs (I would rather use binary search here) can be quite practical.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I'll edit the title to be more descriptive.  If you feel disabling controls one by one is the way to go, and want to add it as an answer, I'll happily +1 it.  If not thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that disabling a subset of controls (not one by one) is a practical method.

In fact, one could do this similarly to a binary search procedure:

1. Base: If you have just one control, this is the faulty control
2. Disable half of the controls and try. If the inefficiency disappears, then the culprit is in the disabled half -- if not, then it is in the remaining half.
3. Continue recursively, applying 2. above to the set of controls that contains the faulty one.

Comment: The binary search methodology was the one I followed to track down which control was causing the issue, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is an issue on one instance but not the other, I think you may be running into one of the issues with Azure: you're not the only tenant on the server.

Something like an XSLT transform is really quite resource intensive; depending on the transform it can take a fair amount of CPU to process.

You may be able to confirm this by re-imaging (not rebooting) the instance. From what I can tell this will create a new virtual machine in the Azure infrastructure that should, hopefully, be located on a different physical machine.

If that fixes the problem then it may be worth investigating a larger instance size. That gets more memory, and I also understand it gets a higher priority for CPU usage, too.

Also: check that the machine with the issues isn't running low on virtual memory. XSLT transforms that do lots of string allocations put extra pressure on memory, so you may see extra garbage collections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I might give the re-imaging a go to see if it helps.  My apologies for being unclear in my post (I'll edit it now) but there are two sites available in each instance, with the second instance being just failover. Of those two sites, one works fine, the other is very slow (despite being served from the same instance, the same IIS etc.).  It's very strange!

Comment: Ah: how is the XSLT transform written, is it e.g. a precompiled regex? If so, the first time it's run, you'll see the delay.

Comment: Well, it's a consistent delay: I've been timing it in Firebug/IE (and using a few other sites like Loads.In) and the response time is the same each time: 10-20 seconds for first page byte.  Do you know of any methods for perhaps digging further into Umbraco to narrow down the delay to one particular XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the transformation ends 11 seconds after it starts doesn't necessarily mean that the XSLT execution has taken 11 seconds. It might have spent most of that time waiting for resources it needs before it can start. A common cause, for example, is that the transformation engine invokes the XML parser and the XML parser requests a DTD to be fetched from a remote web site.

Comment: Hmmm, especially if that DTD doesn't exist... and there's a DNS timeout of, say, ten seconds...

Comment: It turns out the issue was with a Twitter plugin for Umbraco, the delay caused by the turnaroud time to fetch current statuses from the Twitter API :) thank you for the suggestion.